# Extension para ir a archivo desde funcion importada (Visual studio Code)

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio, extensiones

Holaa, quisiera saber si alguien conoce alguna extension que permita (por ejemplo) hacer click en alguna funcion importada de javascript o php y abrir el archivo donde esta creada?. He buscado pero he tenido exito.

Comment: hay algo parecido nativo en vs code, si presionas ctrl+shift+f y pones el nombre de la funcion (o cualquier cosa que quieras buscar) te va a indicar en que archivo esta y si das click sobre el elemento te abre el archivo (funciona con la folder activa)